# Using Odata enabled ASP.NET Web-API to call a Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-odata

All,
Looking for guidance on exposing a Stored Procedure using **OData**.

I'm modifying an existing WEB-API app that already exposes **OData**. It currently exposes tables and views from SQL SERVER, and now I'm required to have it also expose Stored procedures. The current Stored Procedure will accept a bunch of parameters, and push changes to a handful of tables on the back-end database.

Here are the packages used by the project:

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="LinqKit" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Client" version="6.8.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="6.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="6.8.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="6.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="6.8.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="6.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="6.8.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Patches.System.Web.OData" version="5.3.0-datetimefixes" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Dynamic" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I've worked to follow this guide: [Actions and Functions in OData v4 Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions), as I understand that naively supported Stored Procedures is not possible in **OData**.

I've modified my existing application, adding the model, and the wiring inside of WebApiConfig. On my first run I got the following error:

[image]

Goes without saying... There shouldn't be a primary key defined for a stored procedure.

Note that I'm trying to access "vw_tickets_all_tables", and still the error is thrown... inferring that the error breaks the entire application.

Here's the code I have thus far:

**MODEL:**

```
public class InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets : DbContext
{
    public InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets()
            : base("name=InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTicketsBase> InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets { get; set; }
}
public partial class InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTicketsBase
{
    string ticketType{set; get;}
    string category{set; get;}
    string title{set; get;}
    string details{set; get;}
    Nullable<bool> isHtml{set; get;}
    // bunches of fields left out for brevity
    string lastUpdateBy{set; get;}
    string createdBy{set; get;}
    string creationName{set; get;}
    string revisionName{set; get;}
}
```

**WepApiConfig:**

```
public static IEdmModel GetUOMSModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.ContainerName = "UOMSContext";
    builder.EntityType<Models.UOMS.DBO.InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets>()
        .Action("Execute");

    var function = builder.Function("GetParameters");

    function.Parameter<string>("ticketType");
    function.Parameter<string>("category");
    function.Parameter<string>("title");
    function.Parameter<string>("details");
    // bunches of fields left out for brevity
    function.Parameter<int?>("inputTicketId");
    function.Parameter<string>("lastUpdateBy");
    function.Parameter<string>("createdBy");
    function.Parameter<string>("creationName");
    function.Parameter<string>("revisionName");
    function.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Models.UOMS.DBO.InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets>("InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets");
}
```

I'll add a **CONTROLLER** once the "Key" issue is resolved.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a key for the entity type `InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets`?

Because you try to add a entity type `builder.EntityType<Models.UOMS.DBO.InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets>()`
 and create an entity set named `InsertUpdateTicketsPJMTickets`.

From OData spec, each entity type is a structural type with key(s).

You can do:

1. Call Fluent API `HasKey`
2. Add attribute [key] on the property that you want to make it as `key`